# Find the longest diagonal of an element in a matrix-python

Tags: python, matrix, diagonal

I fairly new to programming, so my question may seem naive.
I need a function that given a matrix like this one:

```
m=[['2','3','2','4','2','2','1']
   ['5','2','6','2','7','2','2']
   ['5','3','9','4','2','6','8']]
```

-finds the longest diagonal of the element '2' (it doesn't have to start in row one):

```
['2','2','2']
```

-outputs the position of the first element of the diagonal in the matrix:

```
m[0][2]
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.com, please show you attempt. What did you try yourself? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I can't think of an elegant solution right now, but a brute force approach with nested `for` loops should be pretty straight forward. Did you try anything, Sarah?

Comment: Also, are there any restrictions on the shape of the matrix?

Comment: ALSO, does the diagonal have to start in row 1?

Comment: it doesn't have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result=[0,0]
maxdiag = 0
for i in range (0, len(m)):
  for j in range (0, len(m[i])):
    k = 0;
    while (i+k < len(m) and j+k < len(m[0]) and m[i+k][j+k] == '2'):
      k+=1;
      if (k > maxdiag):
        maxdiag = k;
        result[0]=i;
        result[1]=j;
```

Coordinates are stored in `result`.

This is, in my opinion, the empirical solution.

Iterate over the matrix, and when you find a `'2'`, iterate "diagonally" adding the iterator `k` to `i` and `j` (for example, if you find a `'2'` on `m[1][1]` your loop iterates on `m[2][2]`, `m[3][3]`, etc...), and when you find a higher diagonal than the current one, replace the coordinates in the result (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: This is not a trivial algorithm. Can you explain the general idea to improve your answer?